# GAE 404 NOT_FOUND error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i am trying to deploy my app to GAE but i allways get 404 not found error **on all** pages(jsp) **except for default**. RESTful webservices working without problem. I am using netbeans 7.1.1 and gae 1.6.4.1

When I test it locally, everything works fine without any problem. But when I upload it do gae, allways only default page is available. I tryied almost everything.

I tryied to check whether the files are on GAE using appcfg.cmd. I downloaded my files from GAE and found out that noone is missing so the update process was probably successful.

I tryied to upload it with appcfg script instead of netbeans plugin but the process failed because of:

> *com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.*

I cant simply make it working using appcfg script, searech internet for almost whole day and found no possible solution. Uploading with netbeans plugin worked without problem.

So what can be the reason to allways throw 404 on gae? Please help.

Thx very much. If you need any other info, i will be glad to post it here.

Ok,Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facebookLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login.FacebookLogin</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PlanProcess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Input.PlanProcess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facebookLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/facebooklogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>private</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>private.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>private</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>editPlan</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>editTrainingPlan.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>editPlan</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/trainingplan/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>listplans</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>listTrainingPlans.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>listplans</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/listplans</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>visualize</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>visualize.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>visualize</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/visualize</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>graph</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>graph.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>graph</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/graph/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>created</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>created.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>created</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/created</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>newRecord</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>newRecord.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>newRecord</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/newrecord</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>newPlan</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>newPlan.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>newPlan</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/newplan</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>newExcercise</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>newExcercise.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>newExcercise</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/newexcercise</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.InsertToDb</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testinsert</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>recordProcess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Input.RecordProcess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>recordProcess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/record_process</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>excerciseProcess</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Input.ExcerciseProcess</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>excerciseProcess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/excercise_process</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PlanProcess</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/plan_process</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: We can't possibly help unless you show us some details about your app, starting with your web.xml file.

Comment: I added my whole web.xml file

Comment: try this [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21503068/1897935) . do check for both 1) project structure 2) jdk path

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging and searching, i found out, that if you want to map jsp files

you have to use

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>editPlan</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>**/**xxx.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

instead of

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>editPlan</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>xxx.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

The '/' in path is essential, it will work on loaclhost but not deployed on gae. What a crap...

Answer (score 0):

I never mapped JSPs to anything in `web.xml`. Why do you do that?