# unable to use JSP files in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

**Sample application works , unable to proceed with creating modifications to project**

JDK included in build path (some posts say that lack of that might cause errors)

[image]

Error -> **Error 403 in web page** nothing else printed in console or web page

when I do localhost:8888/test.jsp I get a **404** error

console:

[image]

This works ->

```
<welcome-file>NewFile.html</welcome-file>
```

This FAILS ->

```
<welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
```

my project directory from eclipse

[image]

where am i going wrong or missing something

Comment: try installing in paths without spaces. is there a separate error log file?

Comment: @tgkprog the console is the only log i can find . the _ah/admin/ will work only if it is hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it looked under WAR but it was not under WAR . some internal problem in my eclipse . now fixed**

---

**OLD** 
[image]

---

**NEW**
 [image]

Comment: Good, war is a zip can extract it next time and see what is where and relative to what...